# Is there a simple way to transform [[a;b;c];[d;e;f]] into [[a;d];[b;e];[c;f]] in OCaml?

Tags: list, algorithm, multidimensional-array, ocaml

I'd like to write a function in **OCaml**, using only recursivity that can transform any list of list that look like: `[[a1;...;an];[b1;...bn];...;[z1;...;zn]]` into `[[a1;b1;...;z1];...;[an;...;zn]]` what I've done so far is quite complex, I insert element by element reconstructing a new list every time ... and I'm sure there is a simpler way ...
My code so far:

```ml
let inserer l e i = 
  let rec aux l e i j = 
    match l with
    | [] -> failwith "erreur position inexistante"
    | t::q when j = i -> 
      if List.length t = 0 then 
        [e]::q 
      else
        let t1 = List.hd t in
        let q1 = List.tl t in
        let l1 = t1::e::q1 in
        l1::q
    | t::q -> t::(aux q e i (j+1)) 
  in
  aux l e i 0

let inserer_liste b m =
  let rec aux b m i = 
    match b with
    | [] -> m
    | t::q -> 
      let tmp = inserer m t i in
      aux q tmp (i+1) 
  in
  aux b m 0

let transform u n =
  let rec aux u m =
    match u with
    | []-> m
    | b::q -> 
      let tmp = inserer_liste b m in
      aux q tmp
  in
  aux u (List.init n (fun _ -> []))

let u = [[1;2;3]; [4;5;6]; [7;8;9]]
let l = transform u 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that this transformation is way more natural if you transform an array of lists into a lists of arrays. You can transform into a list of lists afterwards.

```ml
let rec f a = 
  match a.(0) with
  | [] -> []
  | _ :: _ ->
     let hd = Array.map List.hd a in
     for i = 0 to Array.length a - 1 do
        a.(i) <- List.tl a.(i)
     done ;
     hd :: (f a)
```

This consumes the input array, which can be solved by shadowing `f` in the following way :

```
let f a = f (Array.copy a)

let f_list l = List.map Array.to_list (f (Array.of_list l))
```

You could also reallocate a new array at each recursive call, but that would be slower, without any upside except maybe a bit nicer code.

`f_list` is more elegant this way :

```ml
let f_list l = 
  l |> Array.of_list |> f |> List.map Array.to_list
```

There is no error handling in my code : it assumes all list have the same length, but it should be to hard to add it.

Comment: Bringing imperative features like for loops iterating over arrays definitely isn't an idiomatic way to solve this problem. Especially when you're converting back and forth from lists to array and back again.

Comment: Allocating a new array at each iteration would allow to use `Array.map` instead of a for loop. However this is not needed, and there is no `map_inplace` in the `Array` module.
And bounded mutability definitely feel idiomatic to me.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a simple way... Not that I know of but that doesn't say much.

Here's something I tried.

```
let lol =
  [
    [ 1;  2;  3;  4; ];
    [ 5;  6;  7;  8; ];
    [ 9; 10; 11; 12; ];
  ]


let ans =
  List.fold_left
    (
      fun a e ->
        match a with
        | [] -> List.fold_right  (fun e a -> [e]::a) e a
        | _  -> List.fold_right2 (fun b c acc -> (c @ [b])::acc) e a []
    )
    []
    lol

let () =
  List.iter
    (
      fun l ->
        List.iter (fun x -> Printf.printf "%d " x) l; 
        print_newline()
    ) 
    ans
```

After some thought I cam up with this

```
let lol =
  [
    [11; 12; 13; 14; 15; 16; 17; 18; 19; ];
    [21; 22; 23; 24; 25; 26; 27; 28; 29; ];
    [31; 32; 33; 34; 35; 36; 37; 38; 39; ];
    [41; 42; 43; 44; 45; 46; 47; 48; 49; ];
  ]

let rec transpose ll =
  match ll with
  | [] -> []
  | l -> (List.map List.hd l)::
         (
           try
             transpose (List.map List.tl l)
           with
           | _ -> []
         )

let ans = transpose lol

let () =
  List.iter
    (
      fun l -> List.iter (fun x -> Printf.printf "%d " x) l; print_newline()
    )
    ans
```